# Possible UI panel memory leak?

Tags: python, scripting

When I toggle the panel checkbox created by the following code the memory usage count in the info bar starts to climb at an alarming rate. Any idea why this is happening?

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the View3D UI panel"""
    bl_label = "Mesh Stats"
    bl_idname = "MESHSTATS_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, "my_prop")


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Prop name", description="Some tooltip", default=True)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: What is an alarming rate for you? You don't know what Blender does in the background to load the addon. Can you provide more data.

Comment: Memory usage is at about 9M when the panel is loaded and climbs to about 18M after clicking the checkbox a dozen or so times - increasing after each click. Thats almost double the original memory usage. It seems to stop increasing after that level is reached.

Comment: okay so apparently this has something to do with the undo stack. its expected behaviour.

Comment: Ok, very well Where did you find this information that it's expected behavior? Please answer your question yourself and mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: I spoke to one of the developers on the #blendercoders irc channel who said that this was due to the undo stack allocating memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender allocates memory for the undo stack when you perform undo-able actions. There is a limit to this allocation determined by the number of undo steps you have specified. See "User Preferences->Editing->Undo->Steps".